# Set a certain enum to be unavailable

Tags: objective-c, enums

I'm using enums in an SDK I'm developing. My enums are ALLOWED, DENIED, and UNSET. I want to give access to users ALLOWED and DENIED only, leaving out UNSET. UNSET is only used the first time the sdk started and I don't want the users to use the UNSET enum. Is this possible?

This is what I currently have in my .h file:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
ALLOWED = 0,
DENIED,
UNSET
} myStatus
```

Comment: No. You can not make enum value "private".

Comment: Eventually you could remove UNSET from enum and make #define UNSET which would be used internally, first time SDK is started...